# How to change size of slider in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, slider

I have Manipulate function with a few horizontal sliders. When I call ImageSize->Small in Plot within my Manipulate only plot of function is resizing and sliders are still big, so I'd like to make them shorter. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `ImageSize` on the slider. For example

```
Manipulate[{a, b, c},
 {{a, 1, "a"}, .1, 1, .1, ImageSize -> Large},
 {{b, 1, "b"}, .1, 1, .1, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{c, 1, "c"}, .1, 1, .1, ImageSize -> Small}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about it! Thank you!

Comment: Funny though, because Slider[] can take an ImageSize option with two size parameters but that doesn't work with a Manipulate control. Only one parameter works there